# Parametro por URL Fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, concatenación

Tengo una aplicación en React Native, donde necesito pasar en la URL del fetch como parámetro, un valor de un Picker, ¿como podría hacerlo? Gracias.

Codigo del Fetch:

```
Acá necesito pasar el valor del this.state.PickerVehiculo, para obtener la información del codigo, segun el vehiculo seleccionado en el primer Picker

fetch('http://address/api/InventarioMarchamos/obtenerSelectMarchamosCarga/')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson1 => {
    this.setState(
      {
        isLoading2: false,
        dataSource2: responseJson1,
      },
      function() {
        // In this block you can do something with new state.
      }
    );
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Código Picker:

```
  <Picker
      selectedValue={this.state.PickerVehiculo}
       onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({PickerVehiculo: itemValue})} >
        { this.state.dataSource.map((item, key)=>(
         <Picker.Item label={item.Placa} value={item.IdUnidad} key={key}  />)
         )}
    </Picker>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tienes que enviar los datos en la petición que haces, si el servidor al que quieres enviar los datos acepta `application/json` añádelo como cabecera y en el body envías tu JSON, te pongo un ejemplo:

```
const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
const body = { ...tus datos... };
```

ACTUALIZADO:

dentro de tu clase...

```
updatePickerVehicle(value) {
  this.setState({ PicketVehicle: value } () => {
    fetch(`http://address/api/InventarioMarchamos/obtenerSelectMarchamosCarga/${this.state.PicketVehicle}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson1 => {
    this.setState(
      {
        isLoading2: false,
        dataSource2: responseJson1,
      },
      function() {
        // In this block you can do something with new state.
      }
    );
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
  })
}
fetch('http://address/api/InventarioMarchamos/obtenerSelectMarchamosCarga/', { method: 'POST', headers, body: JSON.stringify(body) });
```

**No olvides en tu componente Picker poner un método que lance la función `updatePickerVehicle` pasándole el valor seleccionado.**
Si únicamente tienes que pasar un ID o un string por parámetros puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma, (por defecto el método es GET):

```
fetch(`http://address/api/InventarioMarchamos/obtenerSelectMarchamosCarga/${parametro}`);
```

Luego la respuesta ya la manejas de la forma que consideres.
Espero te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo! Fíjate que efectivamente únicamente lo quiero pasar por un ID, intente con un valor establecido en {parametro} y funciona bien, solo que al momento de querer pasar el id que esta en mi picker Vehiculo, me da error, me marca como undefined el id, podrías ayudarme por favor? Muchas gracias!.

Comment: Claro, haz un consolé.log del dato que quieres pasar y verifica que te llega antes enviar para trazar que llegue correctamente

Comment: Me aparece como vació amigo, tengo una botón donde al presionarlo efectivamente me muestra en un alert el id correctamente según el Picker pero cuando hago el this.state.PickerVehiculo en un const no me lo reconoce. Esta es la función que tengo del botón:   GetPickerSelectedItemValueVehiculo=()=>{alert(this.state.PickerVehiculo); } /// Este es donde le asigno el parámetro a mi Picker: const parametro = this.state.PickerVehiculo;

Comment: Vale pues pásale a la url ‘this.state.PickerVehiculo’ en vez de parametro, lo mismo te he confundido yo con el ejemplo, disculpa si así ha sido.

Comment: Me da el mismo problema amigo, fíjate que acabo de encontrar que  yo tengo asi mi:  constructor(props) this.state = {  PickerVehiculo: ' ' } , luego cambie por esto: constructor(props) this.state = {  PickerVehiculo: 7 } y si me funciona bien como tu me dijiste de pasarle en la url el this,state,PickerVehiculo. Ahora lo quise hacer dinamico y lo puse asi: constructor(props)
   this.state = { PickerVehiculo: this.state.PickerVehiculo } y me aparece undefined is not an object. Como podría solucionarlo? Gracias amigo

Comment: Edito la respuesta para aclarar un poco mejor la situación.

Comment: Te lo agradezco amigo, digite el método que me proporciono y me da error de sintaxis, intente agregar los '}' pero igualmente, disculpa la molestia amigo

Comment: El compoenente Picker que estás utilizando de qué librería es? `material-ui`?

Comment: Es de 'react-native'

Comment: Vale, entonces el evento está bien y debería actualizar correctamente el estado, Podrías pegar el error que te dá?

Comment: Si verdad esta raro, el error me sale en el móvil una pantalla roja, y me dice: TypeError, undefined is not a function (near this.state.dataSource.map). Intento hacer el  alert(this.state.PickerVehiculo); arriba de el fetch y me lo muestra en blanco. Yo creí que se iba a solucionar poniendo el el constructor  PickerVehiculo: this.state.PickerVehiculo, pero igualmente me lo toma como vació